# working with enum on querydsl

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I'm using querydsl-jpa, and I have an entity called DataSourceColumn with an Enum member:

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="COULMN_TYPE")
    private eColumnType columnType;
```

When trying to query that entity:

```
    QDataSourceColumn qDataSourceColumn = QDataSourceColumn.dataSourceColumn;
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);        
    List<DataSourceColumn> kpis = query.from(qDataSourceColumn)
        .where(qDataSourceColumn.columnType.eq(eColumnType.HEAD)))
        .list(qDataSourceColumn);
```

I get an empty list. When trying to select it directly, as

```
    SELECT * FROM DATA_SOURCE_COLUMN WHERE column_type = 'HEAD'
```

I get the required results. It seems to me that I'm using the query by enum in a wrong way - how can I fix it?

**Edit**:
The JPQL that is generated is

```
select dataSourceColumn
from DataSourceColumn dataSourceColumn
where dataSourceColumn.columnType = ?1
```

Comment: Try to log the output of  `query.from(qDataSourceColumn).where(qDataSourceColumn.columnType.eq(eColumnType.HEAD))).toString()`. You'll get the JPQL which QueryDSL is executing.

Comment: @jmvivo, I added it to the question. It seems OK to me...

Comment: So do I. You can try to active the ORM-Implementation logs to get more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it - the problem was in the DB somehow - don't know why.

I used PostgreSql and it didn't work. Then I tried it on SQL Server and it worked. I checked and there was no difference in the column definition between the two databases. And the bug only occured with the Enum using QueryDsl.

So I deleted the table DataSourceColumn table from PostgreSql, and let Hibernate to automatically generate the table from the entity - and then it worked.

Comment: Was it a mistake in your post or do you really have this annotation ```@Column(name="COULMN_TYPE")``` instead of this one : ```@Column(name="COLUMN_TYPE")``` ?

Comment: If you mean to the misspelling of `COULMN` then I can't fully remember that but I guess it was a mistake.